# Ampersand break login form data

Tags: angular, rest, authentication, passwords

I've run into an issue with angular but i don't think it's angular related.

Where if your password (000&111 in my test case) contains ampersand (haven't tried other special characters yet) it break the form data like this:

[image]

What is a correct way tohandle this issue.

Comment: so write '000&111'

Comment: @Zohid i don't get your answer sorry. Can you elaborate?

Comment: if 000&111 so write it works like javascript bitwise operators
Link: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: use it as string '000&111'